# Is there a way to skip some optional arguments in Angular filters?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using built-in currency filter:

```
{{ value | currency }}
```

I want to specify *only the fraction size* and let angular decide what currency symbol to show. How can I do that?
I have only one solution so far:

```
{{ value | currency:undefined:0 }}
```

But I don't really like it :)

Comment: You can define your own filter that only takes the fraction size as argument and delegates to the currency filter.

Answer (score 0):

Using @JB Nizet's suggestion, if you really don't like the `undefined` (it doesn't seem that bad to me), you can make your own filter that uses `currency`:

```
app.filter('currencyDigits', [
    '$filter',
    function($filter) {
        return function(value, digits){
            return $filter('currency')(value, void 0, digits);
        };
    }
]);
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
{{ value | currencyDigits:0 }}
```